# Error in P\Invoke signature

Tags: vb.net, pinvoke

I am getting error when I was trying to use function using p\invoke  with following function

**declaration**

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) HRESULT Get_GetLastHR(HANDLE);
```

**definition**

```
HRESULT Get_GetLastHR(HANDLE _xmlParser ){
return ((FCEXMLParser*)_xmlParser)->GetLastHR();
}
```

**p\Invoke signature used in VB.Net**

```
Public Shared Function Get_GetLastHR(ByVal param0 As System.IntPtr) As Integer
```

****ERROR****

*A call to PInvoke function 'FeeCalculator!FeeCalculator.FeeEngine.FeeEngineMethods::Get_GetLastHR' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.*

Is there any problem with the signature used?

Comment: Like the exception message says, wrong calling convention.  Cdecl, not Stdcall.  You must use `<DllImport>` instead of Declare.

Comment: i am using <dllimport> but its not working.I am not able to pass any parameter to the unmanaged functions , but the fuctions with no parameter and only return type are working properly.

Comment: I dont have web cam right now.i am pasting the declaration part     <DllImport("FeeEngineDll.dll")> _
Public Shared Function Get_GetLastHR(ByVal param0 As System.IntPtr) As Integer

Comment: I have changed code to <DllImport("FeeEngineDll.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>.Its working now.Thanks @hans for your help